# Preact lifecycle (redux state & componentWillReceiveProps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lifecycle, preact

I have a question concerning Preact lifecycle.
I’ve created a jsfiddle that is quiet close to my business use case. 
The use case combines HOC, redux and Preact life cycle.
The idea behind the use case is simple ! I’ve created a red dragging surface and at the end of the drag I want to toggle a value inside my reducer !
I’m surprised that even if `mapStateToProps` is called,  when I log the value of the flag in the the next `componentWillReceiveProps` tick the flag is still not toggled. Here are the logs from the following js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4yzLdtkd/32/

`component will receive props: isDragging
component will receive props: hasDragged
map state to props false
component will receive props: value = true
component will receive props: value = false`

I’ve created the exact same use case with react and the result is different. The flag is directly toggled.
Here are the logs from the following js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/urkuwnLr/9/

`component will receive props: isDragging
component will receive props: hasDragged
map state to props false
component will receive props: value = false`

Is this a bug or does Preact works slightly differently than React regarding life cycle ?